# Are we allowed to make our own image uploaded in different website in our app for download?

Tags: android

We have our own Artwork and photography images uploaded in different websites like Tumblr,500px,Deviantart,Flickr etc.So for every image there will be already some URL which is publicly available for everybody to view or download.

Example of such a URL is : http://40.media.tumblr.com/b12772f7533b6283ca008ba8d7ec2192/tumblr_nsezua4hur1r4xqayo1_500.jpg

Like there will be a lot of URL, and we are able to show this in our app and app let user to download this URL. Since the server is not our own, But the images are our own, are we allowed to use these urls in our app to show as a gallery app and let the user download it to their own.

Is it allowed? This is related to programming, because we have seen same websites providing their own APIs to fetch data. But we dont want too many details, Our requirement is simple, So we are trying to keep it simple and economical.

Comment: In future, if the website modifies the way is generates the URL, you will need to update your each URL. So if you use the API, I suppose it will be better.

Comment: You have to read each service's ToS to see if hotlinking/downloading is allowed. Also notice that when you upload images to certains sites they might be claiming copyright on it - again, read the ToS for each one.

Comment: @Marcelo Can you help us whether this ToS Allows our requirement or not? http://about.deviantart.com/policy/service/

Comment: @PrerakSola URLs wont change really.But we are not sure, But thats ok since we dont have 1000's of our own pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine, but check that the URLs don't change, or you'll be left with a lovely little error.